# how to encode special characters in Wordpress web address?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url-encoding

This is my site url. `www.mysite.com`
It has some pages something like `www.mysite.com/about/page1`

From the above URL How can we encode "/" to "%2F" using .htaccess?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do that manually using .htaccess. Go to Dashboard > Settings > Permalinks and there you can change all the rules for urls.

Comment: We could change the url structure but there is no option to encode special characters in url.